# jackson: saving part of original message to jsonb

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jackson, jsonb

i receive a json message. i deserialize most fields but there is one field i don't have to deserialize but i have to save into db. it can be any json object:

```
{
  "important_field": 123,
  "unimportant" : {...}
}
```

so i'm deserializing it as

```
int important_field;
JsonObject unimportant;
```

and now i need to save it to postgres. `unimportant` field is mapped as jsonb. and of course when i try to save it using spring:

```
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("insert into my_table (default, ?,?)", list)
```

i get:

> PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.

how can i save it? do i have to manually serialize the `unimportant` field? or maybe there is some better way to deserialize the message that will be easier to save?

Comment: I don't know about Spring but we're doing something similar using Hibernate and there basically are 2 ways: 1) provide a custom usertype that tells Hibernate how to serialize `JsonObject` (we're mostly using this) and 2) do it manually and pass the json as a string (might need some cast in the query) (we basically only use this with native queries) - Spring probably provides something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to serialize it before to a string and then use explicit type casting/conversion:

```java
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("insert into my_table (default, ?, ?::jsonb)", list)
```

As JSON is a textual format anyway, there is no performance benefit if the driver would do that for you.